# Is it possible to print multiple pages of a draft in Office 365 OWA?

Tags: printing, office365, outlook-web-access

I have a group of users that regularly print drafts of messages in Microsoft's latest version of OWA (Kiosk licenses), but they currently can only do so by copying and pasting the text into a word processor. I have tried using CTRL + P in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome along with IE 8 and IE 10, but it will only print one page. In addition, a print preview shows only one page. Does anyone know if it is possible to make it print multiple pages this way, or are we stuck copying/pasting (or purchasing client licenses)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is a feature in Outlook, it appears that Microsoft took this ability out as a design decision, and it currently seems impossible to print more than one page using the above method.